# How to get a text file in a one dimensional array

Tags: java

I need to figure out how to get a text file of passengers in a one dimensional array, and split it up by name, street address, city, state, weight, and seat number. I have tried using a while loop and a for loop to do this and I cannot get anything going. This is what I have so far.

This is my main method

```
 import java.util.Scanner; 
 import java.io.*; 


 public class Trip_Jarrad 
{
    public static void main(String[]args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
     Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("PassengerList.txt")); 
     Passengers[] passengers = new Passengers[16]; 
        }

         }
```

This is my object class

```
public class Passengers {
String fullName;
String streetAddress;
String city; 
String state;
double weight; 
String seatNum; 

public Passengers(String n, String s, String c, String st, double w, String seat) {

fullName = n; 
streetAddress = s; 
city = c; 
state = s; 
weight = w; 
seatNum = seat; 
}

public String getName() {
    return fullName; 
}

public String getAddress() {
    return streetAddress; 
}

public String getCity() {
    return city; 
}

public String getState() {
    return state; 
}

public double getWeight() {
    return weight; 
}

public String getSeat() {
    return seatNum; 
}


public String toString() {
    return " " +fullName+ "" +streetAddress+ "" +city+ "" +state+ "" +weight+ "" + seatNum; 
}
```

And this is the text file that I am trying to get read.

```
  Jarrad/Self/9 Ely Trail/Yodaloo, Ga/231.2/ 
  Paul/Murray/123 Chenango Street/Montrose, Pa/212.3/
  Allison/Lewis/1884 Vestal Parkway/Vestal, Ny/108.2/
  Theresa/Grabowski/296 Oak Street/Goshen, Ny/121.1/
  David/Parker/133 Pennsylvania Ave/Springfield, Ma/189.7/
  Stephen/Post/722 Newark Valley Road/Owego, Ny/245.0/
  Emily/Post/722 Newark Valley Road/Owego, Ny/174.9/
  Deborah/George/143 Alpine Road/Las Vegas, Nv/145.2/
  Allen/George/143 Alpine Road/Las Vegas, Nv/312.7/
  Judy/Hellman/18801 Jefferson Ave/Brentwood, Ca/134.4/
  Joel/Aylesworth/56 Washington Street/Akron, Oh/322.2/
  Marci/Podder/1884A San Clemente Ave/Apple Valley, Ca/113.1/
  Allen/Parker/129 Trenton Street/Springfield, Ma/134.3/
  Trisha/Johnson/2978 Utica Avenue/Syracuse, Ny/167.2/
  Mike/Squier/546 Owego Avenue/Maine, Ny/113.4/
  Meg/Merwin/123 Appleton Lane/Endicott, Ny/114.8
```

Comment: Don't remove the contents of your question after you got a solution (whether that will be just spamming dots or writing some salutation instead of it). If someone has a similar problem, they will not find this because they don't look for "Thanks everyone for your replies, it really helped me out.". Also if one of the answers solved your problem, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Comment: You might be reading-in your file's contents (into your 'file'-object), and you might initializing your array (ie: your 'passengers'-object) but you certainly aren't iterating over your file-obj (via a for/while-loop or anything else for that matter), so how do you expect that you're setting any values from your file-obj into your passengers-obj? I know you said you've tried both for/while-loops and can't get anything to work but you need to provide examples of what you've done and what the problem is.

Comment: Also, statically initializing your array (ie: [16]) is generally very bad practice. Unless you have an explicit reason for doing so, you'd be far better served using an ArrayList instead of an array.

Answer (score 1):

To split a string in Java, use String.split() method:

```
String s = "Jarrad/Self/9 Ely Trail/Yodaloo, Ga/231.2/";
String[] array_split = s.split("/");
// the array is {"Jarrad", "Self", "9 Ely Trail", "Yodaloo", "Ga", "231.2"}
```

Answer (score 0):

First we call `sc.nextLine()` to get a whole line from the `File`.

Then we use [`String[] split(String regex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) to split the term into its separate values and pass them to the constructor

```
Scanner sc;

Passenger[] passengers = new Passenger[16];
for (int i = 0; i < passengers.length; i++) {
    String[] values = sc.nextLine().split("/");
    String fullName = values[0] + values[1];
    // todo: init remaining values
    Passenger passenger; // todo: initialise
    passengers[i] = passenger;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the NIO files API, you can easily convert your lines into a list of `Passenger` objects:

```
List<Passengers> passengers = java.nio.file.Files
    .lines(java.nio.file.Paths.get( "PassengerList.txt"))
    .map(line -> line.trim().split("/"))
    .map(arr -> new Passengers(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3], Double.parseDouble(arr[4]), arr[5]))
    .collect(java.util.stream.Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Unfortunately the values in the file don't map 1:1 to the parameters in the constructor. maybe put it into an external function?